# Is it possible to calculate a chord perpendicular to the focal point of a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, plane-geometry

I wanted to know if there is a way to calculate a chord that spans a circle, perpendicular to the origin point of the circle. In the image below, I need a way to calculate the length of the blue line that intersects the green dot perpendicular to the origin point of the circle. The red line is just to illustrate what I mean by perpendicular to the origin. For this problem, I know the coordinates of the green dot, and the coordinates of the focal point of the circle (0,0). Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Yes. You know the slope of the red line, and therefore the slope of the blue line (negative reciprocal). You have a point, and can find the equation of the blue line. Then you can determine the intersection points on the circle and find the distance between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $AB$ be the chord, $D$ be the green dot and $O$ be the origin (as well as the center of the circle). Then you can calculate the length of $OD$ since you know their coordinates. Furthermore, $OA$ and $OB$ are just the radii of the circle, and you get the answer by the Pythagorean theorem easily from here.

Comment: Thanks! I think I see what you mean!